# Autohotkey script for copying specific content inside the brackets by clicking anywhere inside these brackets

Tags: autohotkey

I want to make an Autohotkey script, so I ask you for a little help.

I work as a transcriptionist, and in my text I often have timecodes in the following format (00:00:00). I need a script what will help me to copy to clipboard a timecode in the format 00:00:00 (without brackets) by clicking to any place inside these brackets (for example Alt+LClick).

Now I use the following script, but it is hardcoded and I must click exactly in the middle of the timecode, otherwise it doesn't work:

```
!LButton:: 
    Send {Click 2}
    Sleep 100
    Send {Right 4}{Shift Down}{Left 8}{Shift Up}
    Send ^c
return
```

So I want an improved and more versatile script. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you provide some example text?

Comment: Hello!

Here is a video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RL51VK4va3l0Z4Mn-WCqY93_Ltxf0QvR/view?usp=sharing

I Alt+Click in the middle of timecode and copy it to the clipboard.
But I need a script with copies timecode by clicking to any place inside two brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something like this if you want to select one by one.

```
~LButton::  ;   Hold the left button to select
    now := A_TickCount
    While GetKeyState( "LButton", "P" )
        if( A_TickCount - now > 300 )   {
            ;   Just incremented the range
                Send {AltUp}{Right 10}{Shift Down}{Left 20}{Shift Up}
            Send ^c
            Sleep, 100
            ;   Filter characters between "(" and ")"
            Clipboard := StrReplace( StrReplace( RegExReplace( Clipboard, "[^\)]+(\(|$)"), ")" ), "(")  ;   Can be better than this, but im not good with regex
            Send {Right}
            ; Just for test
                ToolTip % Clipboard
                Sleep, 1000
                Tooltip
        }
Return
```

Or you can select the entire text and filter all result at once.

```
F1:: ; ANY HOTKEY YOU WANT
    Clipboard := "Lorem Ipsum is simply (00:00:57) dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived (00:01:51) not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic (01:23:11) typesetting, remaining essentially (00:10:23) unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"
    Clipboard := StrReplace( StrReplace( RegExReplace( Clipboard, "[^\)]+(\(|$)","`n"), ")" ), "(") ;   Can be better than this, but im not good with regex
    ToolTip % Clipboard
    Sleep, 1000
    Tooltip
Return
```

Comment: You are welcome.
If you gonna use the second example, remember to remove the line "Clipboard := "Lorem Ipsum ..."